# how to make full width and height imageView with admob displayed?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-glide

I'm facing a problem with Glide image displayed in an imageview..
I've searched this great site for answers and other sites, but no hit to the goal !

1- first question: i want to display image with full width and full height of imageview ..

2- second question: how to make a scroll-able imageview with full width ...

Please help me !! I'm using GLIDE library and i used many Other libraries for image transformation ( BigImageView ..)

thanks for your help

This is the code for DisplayImg Activity

```
public class DisplayImg extends AppCompatActivity {

Context c ;
PhotoViewAttacher photoViewAttacher;
private AdView mAdView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_img);



    ImageView imageView =  findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    GlideApp
            .with(this).load(R.drawable.display)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
            .into(imageView);


    photoViewAttacher=new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);



    // Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);









    // Making notification bar transparent
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    changeStatusBarColor();
}

private void changeStatusBarColor() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
}
```

}

The layout code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".DisplayImg">

<com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/display"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
    ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

[This is the current now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7Jij.png)

Comment: post the code of what you have done so far

Comment: thanks, please see the code

Comment: so your question is how to use the entire width of the screen and a scrollable height for the image? And please post your xml too.

Comment: Yes .. exactly  .. please see the code

Comment: please check the code now ! layout included

Answer (score 1):

Change you xml like this and tell me if this works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/display"
        android:scaleType = "fitXY"/>

</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Man ! You're Genius !! Thanks bro

Comment: it worked in phones ! but on tablets it didn't work! please help

Comment: I don't have my lap with me now so can't use android studio, i'll get back to you later. Also, upvotes are the real way to show appreciation ;)

Comment: @Frankensteinleb Hey sorry i'm late. I updated the code, please check  now. I tested in a nexus 7 and one plus 3 and it was working fine.